# Advice on this UI implementation?

Tags: android, xml, layout, user-interface

Here's the basic UI i intend:

[image: start]
[image: rotate]
[image: end]

There is central circle:CENTER. As the view is rotated, new circles:NAME are generated on the circumference. The circle at the top is a newly generated circle, i.e. if an already generated  circle passes the top it fetches a new name.

I don't know the Android API well enough yet, so can someone point me in the right direction? What classes should I look at? How can I create that sort of pathing? Do I generate circle programmatically or have the views already in the xml layout but invis?

Thanks.

EDIT: Currently I'm working on the custom views that will be each circle.

Comment: Did you check to make sure that Apple has not patented the circle?

Comment: didn't know apple did this. I'd think this is pretty common. If so link? And how would one check?

Comment: Sorry if my apple loathing scarcasm dripping comment confused you :)

Comment: Oh here is the link for reference. http://www.forbes.com/sites/timworstall/2012/04/01/apple-claims-patent-rights-to-the-rectangle/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could do it by extending [AdapterView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html). I would start by looking at the source code for it and some of its decedents to see how they implemented them.

The functionality you are after I don't think is very far removed from a ListView or some of the other simple Adapter ready View widgets.

The main difference is going to be your onDraw() method, you'll need to override that to draw the circles for you. Whether you make the circles programmatically or define your own views in xml is going to depend on how you want to appear visually.

I don't have any sample code for the rotation effect you are after but surely it can be accomplished with a canvas and some geometry.

Once you've got the AdapterView built you'll also probably want to subclass an Adapter to hold your names and override its getView() method to populate the names into the circles for you.

If you have not ever implemented any of the ViewGroup widgets I suggest you start by exploring some of those. ListView, GridView, etc.. Learn how to use it with an adapter and some data to create the dynamic layout. Once you have a good understanding of how to use the ones that are already built then start trying to tackle the one you want to make.

Comment: I would say not to draw the circles themselves in the onDraw. Just use that to place each view. Allow the view you return (from your getView() function) to be circular. That way you have a more generic AdapterView that is simply spinning views. Also the center view doesn't need to actually be attached to the adapter view. It'll probably be easier to have it as a separate view in your layout and just have hooks between the two...

Comment: Hi, I intend to make the circles atomic custom view objects. Does that change anything?

Comment: nope will still work the same. @SalilPandit good point. I think you'd still need to use onDraw() to get the rotation effect though.Hmm Some kind of property animator and some geometry might be able to give you the rotation effect you are after too though.

Comment: You could use an animation, or in the onDraw of the AdapterView you can use the `canvas.rotate();` function where you rotate the canvas by doing `canvas.rotate(currentDegree,...); currentDegree+=ROTATE_SPEED; if(currentDegree >= 360) {currentDegree = 0;} invalidate();` I <b>think</b> that should create an infinite spin... Then all you have to do is place the views in a circle around it as normal...